# Troubles with permissions of a new user on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, git, permissions, console, environment-variables

I want to create a new user and give him possibility to use git. So, I've installed git:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

After that I've created a user:

```
sudo useradd -d /home/developer -s /bin/bash -g sudo -m developer
```

And now I have a problem. When I switch to a new user and try to do something like this:

```
git clone <<here is a path>>
```

I get this error message:

```
fatal: unable to access '/home/roman/.config/git/config': Permission denied
```

I can't get why environment variables points to another user folders and what is the good way to fix it. I also believe that I didn't specify something properly during creation of a new user (that is why environment variables have not proper values).

The same problem appears when I try for instance to run mc... I get this:

```
Cannot create /home/roman/.config/mc directory
```

For more information have this

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep developer

developer:x:1001:27::/home/developer:/bin/bash
```

So, can somebody explain me how to solve my problems?

Comment: Did you login as user 'developer'? What is the output of `whoami'?

Comment: Common, I switched to developer. The output of `whoami` is developer as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

To switch to the new user `developer`, try using one of:

- `sudo -H -u developer` (this changes the `HOME` environment variable to that of the target user)
- `su - developer` (this sets up the target user's environment as if they had logged in)

Comment: Actually I switched to another user with `su developer` and it was useless... And `sudo -H -u developer` - what is this? I got just usage promt.